# Does using the noarchive tag affect the page rankings?

Tags: seo, search-engine-indexing

Has anyone heard of any ranking impact for the pages where the noarchive tag is used?

They are indexable (and indexed), but just wondered if there are any case studies showing that disallowing Google from keeping a cache version of your page had an impact on its visibility in SERPs.

Comment: Short answer. No. There is no metric for that. It is a simple binary switch to display the stored page or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No! Using `Noarchive` meta tag will not affect the page rank or It will not penalize your page.

An [article](http://www.searchenginejournal.com/when-why-and-how-to-use-noarchive/7422/) from SEJ saying,

> Can you get penalized for using noarchive on your pages? – Apparently,
>   no. But some people treat sites with unavailable cache version with
>   suspicion: “when I see pages not cached my first thought is that
>   they’re cloaking“. SEO rumors never stop, and one of them has it, that
>   noarchive used to be a red flag – I personally don’t think so.
>   Officially, Google also states, there’s nothing wrong with webmasters
>   using the tag:
>
> This tag only removes the “Cached” link for the page. Google will continue to index the page and display a snippet.

So if you use `Noarchive` meta tag in a page you don't need to worry about the SERP of that page.